# Clipping in DrawingML

Tags: docx, drawingml

I am creating Word DOCX files with embedded vector graphics. Apparently DrawingML is now the preferred way of inserting vector graphics. I am having trouble working out how to clip a diagram within the drawing canvas. It seems to keep scaling my shapes within the group shape.

Is clipping possible in DrawingML, and if so, does anyone have a wee snippet of code or XML to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you post example XML you would like to clip (eg your w:drawing element)?

Answer (score 2):

Cropping in DrawingML is from the `<scrRect/>` tag. If it is anything but empty, it means it is cropped. This tag is used for all visual graphics, such as images, shapes, charts, etc.

Take these two examples of an .EMF inserted in Word:

```
    <w:drawing>
      <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
        <wp:extent cx="5934456" cy="7269480"/>
        <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="9525" b="7620"/>
        <wp:docPr id="1" name="Picture 1" descr="C:\Users\Todd\Pictures\Dotted_Lines.emf"/>
        <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
          <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/>
        </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
        <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
          <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
            <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
              <pic:nvPicPr>
                <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="Picture 1" descr="C:\Users\Todd\Pictures\Dotted_Lines.emf"/>
                <pic:cNvPicPr>
                  <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="1" noChangeArrowheads="1"/>
                </pic:cNvPicPr>
              </pic:nvPicPr>
              <pic:blipFill>
                <a:blip r:embed="rId5">
                  <a:extLst>
                    <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                      <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
                    </a:ext>
                  </a:extLst>
                </a:blip>
                <a:srcRect/>
                <a:stretch>
                  <a:fillRect/>
                </a:stretch>
              </pic:blipFill>
              <pic:spPr bwMode="auto">
                <a:xfrm>
                  <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                  <a:ext cx="5934456" cy="7269480"/>
                </a:xfrm>
                <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                  <a:avLst/>
                </a:prstGeom>
                <a:noFill/>
                <a:ln>
                  <a:noFill/>
                </a:ln>
              </pic:spPr>
            </pic:pic>
          </a:graphicData>
        </a:graphic>
      </wp:inline>
    </w:drawing>
```

and

```
<w:drawing>
          <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" wp14:anchorId="779C87CB" wp14:editId="4B126F88">
            <wp:extent cx="3390181" cy="4882551"/>
            <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="1270" b="0"/>
            <wp:docPr id="2" name="Picture 2" descr="C:\Users\Todd\Pictures\Dotted_Lines.emf"/>
            <wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
              <a:graphicFrameLocks xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main" noChangeAspect="1"/>
            </wp:cNvGraphicFramePr>
            <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
              <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                <pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture">
                  <pic:nvPicPr>
                    <pic:cNvPr id="0" name="Picture 1" descr="C:\Users\Todd\Pictures\Dotted_Lines.emf"/>
                    <pic:cNvPicPr>
                      <a:picLocks noChangeAspect="1" noChangeArrowheads="1"/>
                    </pic:cNvPicPr>
                  </pic:nvPicPr>
                  <pic:blipFill rotWithShape="1">
                    <a:blip r:embed="rId5">
                      <a:extLst>
                        <a:ext uri="{28A0092B-C50C-407E-A947-70E740481C1C}">
                          <a14:useLocalDpi xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main" val="0"/>
                        </a:ext>
                      </a:extLst>
                    </a:blip>
                    <a:srcRect l="23111" r="19768" b="32841"/>
                    <a:stretch/>
                  </pic:blipFill>
                  <pic:spPr bwMode="auto">
                    <a:xfrm>
                      <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                      <a:ext cx="3389885" cy="4882125"/>
                    </a:xfrm>
                    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                      <a:avLst/>
                    </a:prstGeom>
                    <a:noFill/>
                    <a:ln>
                      <a:noFill/>
                    </a:ln>
                    <a:extLst>
                      <a:ext uri="{53640926-AAD7-44D8-BBD7-CCE9431645EC}">
                        <a14:shadowObscured xmlns:a14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2010/main"/>
                      </a:ext>
                    </a:extLst>
                  </pic:spPr>
                </pic:pic>
              </a:graphicData>
            </a:graphic>
          </wp:inline>
        </w:drawing>
```

Note that they are the same, except for the line `<a:srcRect l="23111" r="19768" b="32841"/>` in the second one. What this means is that the source rectangle (i.e. the image's dimensions) is cut/clipped/cropped by 23.111% off the left, 19.768% off the right and 32.841% off the bottom. The top has not been cropped.

Comment: Can you confirm whether this still applies if the content is not an emf? Certainly in Word, having an inline canvas with DrawingML in it there is no Ui option to crop it; whereas there is if the content is a bitmap. Is this only available if the docx is directly edited? Also, I converted an EMF to a shape and the cropped parts became included in the canvas, shrinking the overall drawing!!

Comment: `scrRect` only applies to blips (i.e. bitmap images of any type) - it does not apply to custom geometries (`custGeom`) or VML. In Word 2007, when a vector blip is deconstructed to a set of geometries, it becomes VML. In Word 2010, it becomes first a set of `custGeom` with the `wpc` namespace (WordProcessingCanvas) and then has a fallback of VML so it can be displayed in Word 2007. In either case, neither allow for the whole canvas to be clipped, in the UI or in code, only the individual parts.